# Iterate through dictionary React Js not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a dictionary named CarValues in my code which contains following data:

dictionary: CarValues

key ==> string

Value ==> Array

1. key => Honda, Value => white, yellow, red, orange
2. key => Toyota, Value => white, yellow, green, black
3. Key => Volkswagen Value => 123, 456, 343

I want to iterate through the key and generate a string something like below:

var merge = Honda**Car**='white'&Honda**Car**='yellow'&Honda**Car**='red'&Honda**Car**='orange'&Toyota**Car**='white'&Toyota**Car**='yellow'&Toyota**Car**='green'&Toyota**Car**='black'&Volkswagen**Car**=123&Volkswagen**Car**=456&Volkswagen**Car**=343

I have something like below in one of the methods in the class:

```
    var merge = '';
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.state.CarValues).map(function(key){
        for (var x in key.values) {
            merge= merge.concat('&' + key + '='" + x + "'");
        }
```

I am not sure what is wrong but the above is not working. it says key is undefined while execution.

Also tried below,

```
    Object.keys(this.state.CarValues).map((key) => (
        **for (var value in  vals[key] }) {**
            merge = merge.concat('&' + key + '='" + x + "'");
        }
    **))**
```

But the above throws error at the compilation saying Expression expected at highlighted lines in bold.

Comment: the value property in the data is an array or string with comma separated items? the solutions depends upon what data type it is.

Comment: value property in the data is an array. let me add that. thanks!

Comment: In addition to the solutions below, the reason why your second attempt fails is because, when using an arrow function and `()` for the body, it expects an expression (like `1 + 2`) and not a statement (like `for (...) {}`). If you replace them with curly brackets `{}`, it'll work fine

Comment: @kingdaro Thanks. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like this: (don't forget to add `this.state.`)

```js
const CarValues = {
    Honda: ['white', 'yellow', 'red', 'orange'],
    Toyota: ['white', 'yellow', 'green', 'black'],
    Volkswagen: [123, 456, 343]
}

var q = Object.entries(CarValues)
    .map( ([key, value]) => `${key}=` + value.join(`&${key}=`))
    .join('&');

console.log(q)
```

Comment: That worked great. I liked the way the code was written. Clean and neat. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Vicky, happy to help!

Comment: One more question, what would be the best way to delete the keyValue pair completely from above CarValues object like for example Honda and its value (entire record) from above code.

Comment: @Vicky, `delete CarValues.Honda`

Answer (score 0):

assuming your data structure is like:

```
const cars = {
  Honda: ["white", "yellow", "red", "orange"],
  Toyota: ["white", "green"],
  Volkswagon: [123, 456]
};
```

and you want the output:
HondaCar='white'&HondaCar='yellow'&HondaCar='red'&HondaCar='orange'ToyotaCar='white'&ToyotaCar='green'VolkswagonCar='123'&VolkswagonCar='456'

How about this:

```
const { cars } = this.state;
const keys = Object.keys(cars);
const s = keys.reduce((acc, car) => {
  const colours = cars[car].map(val => {
    return `${car}Car='${val}'`;
  });
  return `${acc}${colours.join('&')}`;
}, "");
console.log(s);
```

Comment: I think that should work. But, haven't tried as I used the below one. Thanks a lot! @nikrb.